# Max and min of $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt y} \log(\frac {5}{4} y^2+x^2-4x+4 )$ on $D$

Tags: real-analysis

$D$ is $\{(x,y): (x-2)^2+\frac{y^2}{4}=1\}$. If I consider $f$ on $D$ I found: $g(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt y} \log(1+y^2)$. Have I to study max and min of $g$ to find max and min of $f$?

Answer (score 0):

So you've found that for $(x,y)\in D$ we have
$$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}\log\Big(\frac{5}{4}y^2+x^2-4x+4\Big)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}\log(1+y^2).$$

Now, on $D$ we have $-2\leq y\leq 2$, so the question is a bit dodgy since $f$ is not defined for $y\leq 0$. If this doesn't bother you too much, we could examine the behaviour of $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}\log(1+y^2)$$
for $y>0$ to see what its limit is as $y\to 0$ (if any) and its maxima or minima on $y\geq 2$ (if any).

For the limit $$\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\log(1+y^2)}{\sqrt{y}}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\frac{2y}{1+y^2}}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}}=0,$$
where we've used L'Hopital's rule.

The derivative of the expression is $$\frac{2\sqrt{y}}{1+y^2}-\frac{\log(1+y^2)}{2y^{3/2}},$$

which I can't be bothered to solve.